# how to show api error instead default error message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, error-handling

I have my api built in Nodejs.
this is response on any error I'm sending

```
res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    success:false,
    message:err.message,
})
}
```

and when I call api with axios -

```
 api.post("/api/v2/users/login", {
        email: loginEmail,
        password: loginPassword
      })
      .then((res) => {
      // do something
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
```

log -

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

but I want to see message that I'm sending in api as error. for that  I see in chrome > inspect > network > response

```
{"success":false,"message":"Email or password invalid"}
```

how Can I log above message ?? I want to show this message in frontEnd. Reactjs

- I'm on MERN stack

Answer (score 0):

[solution] instead of log(e), I did this, and it worked

```
console.log(e.response.data.message);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).